# Prove that $_4F_3\left(\frac13,\frac13,\frac23,\frac23;1,\frac43,\frac43;1\right)=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac13\right)^6}{36 \pi ^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function, elliptic-integrals

I found an interesting [problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66423/hard-hypergeometric-4f3) about generalized hypergeometric series in MO, stating that:

> $$\, _4F_3\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3};1,\frac{4}{3},\frac{4}{3};1\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(\frac13)_k (\frac23)_k}{(1)_k (\frac43)_k}\right)^2=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^6}{36 \pi ^2}$$

This numerically agrees, but I found no proof using either elementary properties of hypergeometric functions (e.g. cyclic sum) or classical Gamma formulas (e.g. Dougall formula). I bet it has something to do with modular forms and elliptic $K$ integral, but the exact relation remain elusive.

**How to prove this identity**? What will be its motivation? Can we generate other Gamma evaluation of high order hypergeometric series using the method of proving it? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Might be related to $K(k_3)^2$ in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html, however, the proportionality constant is $1152 \cdot 2^{1/3}3^{1/6}$ which is quite ugly

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let $S$ be the given $_4F_3$, then (first equality comes from termwise integration),
$$\begin{aligned}
S &= -\frac{1}{9}\int_0^1 t^{-2/3} (\log t) {_2F_1}(2/3,2/3;1;t)dt  =-\frac{1}{9} \frac{d}{da} \left(\int_0^1 t^{-2/3+a} {_2F_1}(2/3,2/3;1;t)dt \right)_{a=0}\\ &= -\frac{1}{9}\frac{d}{da}\left(\frac{\, _3F_2\left(\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3},a+\frac{1}{3};1,a+\frac{4}{3};1\right)}{ a+1/3}\right)_{a=0} \end{aligned}$$

It is easily seen $A=\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{7}{6}\right)/\Gamma \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2$ is the value of the $_3F_2$ at $a=0$ ([Dixon](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DixonsTheorem.html)). Set
$$\begin{aligned}
&{d_{2/3}} = \frac{d}{{da}}{\left( {{_3F_2}(\frac{2}{3} + a,\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{3};1,\frac{4}{3};1)} \right)_{a = 0}} \qquad {d_1} = \frac{d}{{da}}{\left( {{_3F_2}(\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{3};1 + a,\frac{4}{3};1)} \right)_{a = 0}} \\
&{d_{1/3}} = \frac{d}{{da}}{\left( {{_3F_2}(\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{3} + a;1,\frac{4}{3};1)} \right)_{a = 0}} \qquad {d_{4/3}} = \frac{d}{{da}}{\left( {{_3F_2}(\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{3};1,\frac{4}{3} + a;1)} \right)_{a = 0}}\end{aligned}$$

By multivariable chain rule, $$S = A -\frac{1}{3}(d_{1/3}+d_{4/3})\tag{*}$$

---

In general, derivative of $_pF_q$ with respect to a parameter is intractable. One can only handle them in an *ad hoc* manner. In our situation, it is well-known that $_3F_2$ at $1$ satisfies certain transformations: two generators are the 1st and 3rd entry [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/17/02/06/). Using these two entries, we obtain
$$\begin{aligned}
& \quad _3F_2\left(\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3},a+\frac{1}{3};1,a+\frac{4}{3};1\right) \\ &= \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \Gamma \left(a+\frac{4}{3}\right) \, _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3}-a;1,\frac{4}{3};1\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{4}{3}\right) \Gamma \left(a+\frac{2}{3}\right)} \\
&= \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \, _3F_2\left(a+\frac{1}{3},a+\frac{2}{3},a+\frac{2}{3};a+1,a+\frac{4}{3};1\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}-a\right) \Gamma (a+1)} \\ &= \frac{\Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right) \Gamma \left(a+\frac{1}{3}\right) \Gamma \left(a+\frac{4}{3}\right) \, _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3};\frac{4}{3},a+1;1\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2 \Gamma \left(a+\frac{2}{3}\right) \Gamma (a+1)}+\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \Gamma \left(a+\frac{1}{3}\right) \Gamma \left(a+\frac{4}{3}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \Gamma \left(a+\frac{2}{3}\right)^2}
\end{aligned}$$

Observe that for all four $_3F_2$ above, their arguments are all like $(2/3,2/3,1/3;1,4/3)$, the only difference is $a$ appears at different places. This reveals why $(2/3,2/3,1/3;1,4/3)$ is special.

Introduce an operational definition: write $x\equiv y$ if $x-y$ is a "linear combination of gamma factors". For example, $x\equiv y$ if $x-y = A$. Now take derivative at $a=0$, we obtain
$$\tag{**}d_{1/3}+d_{4/3} \equiv -d_{2/3} \equiv d_{1/3}+2d_{2/3}+d_1+d_{4/3} \equiv -d_1$$
Solving this system gives
$$d_1 \equiv d_{2/3} \equiv d_{1/3}+d_{4/3} \equiv 0$$

Thus $d_{1/3}+d_{4/3}$ can be expressed into gamma function, so can $S$ according to $(*)$.

There is no difficulty in making $(**)$ explicit:
$$d_{1/3}+d_{4/3}=\left(3-\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{3}}\right) A-d_{2/3}=d_1+d_{1/3}+2 d_{2/3}+d_{4/3}+\frac{1}{6} A \left(\sqrt{3} \pi -9 \log (3)\right)=-d_1+\frac{1}{2} A \left(\pi  \sqrt{3}-6+3 \log (3)\right)+\frac{3 \left(3 \sqrt{3}-2 \pi \right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2 \Gamma \left(\frac{7}{6}\right)^2}{\sqrt[3]{2} \pi ^2}$$

Solving gives $d_{1/3}+d_{4/3} = \dfrac{2 \sqrt{\pi } \left(27-4 \sqrt{3} \pi \right) \Gamma \left(\frac{13}{6}\right)}{21 \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2}$. We also obtain values of $d_1, d_{2/3}$ as by-products.

Comment: It's quite a nice solution. I actually think that if you can generalize it a bit you might be able to make a small publication out of it. For instance, if you get the case for general that I mention below, or generalize it in some other way.

Answer (score 5):

Wow, amazing! Solved 9 years later! Thanks all for digging this up, and then for solving it. Can this give a general form for

$$_4F_3(\frac1m,\frac1m,\frac2m,\frac2m;\frac{m+1}m,\frac{m+1}m,1;1)$$

I should probably give some motivations for this. In the following paper, I looked at the expected exit time of a planar Brownian motion starting at 0 from a regular $m$-gon centered at 0:

https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ecp/1465262013

It is (up to a constant which depends on the size of the polygon)

$$_4F_3(\frac1m,\frac1m,\frac2m,\frac2m;\frac{m+1}m,\frac{m+1}m,1;1)\times \frac{m^2}{\beta(1/m,(m-2)/m)^2},$$

which doesn't exactly roll off the tongue. However, for an equilateral triangle there is a different method for calculating this, and it gives $1/6$. So we get an identity by equating the two, and that is the identity. Now, the question is, can we use this method to get a nicer expression for the $_4F_3$ for larger $m$? This would then be a nicer expression for the expected exit time of Brownian motion from the regular $m$-gon.

A purely analytic (i.e. not probabilistic) version of this all can be found here, because the expected exit time is basically the Hardy H^2 norm of the domain, up to a constant.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.2458

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1**: Evaluating
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}\,_2F_1\left ( \frac23,\frac23;
1;x \right )\text{d}x,
$$
gives
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\left ( x^{s-1}+
\frac{1-\sqrt{3}\cot(\pi s) }{2}x^{-s-\frac13}  \right ) 
\,_2F_1\left ( \frac23,\frac23;
1;x \right )\text{d}x
=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}\cot(\pi s) }{2} \frac{2\pi\sqrt{3} }{\Gamma\left ( \frac13 \right )^3 }
\int_{0}^{1} x^{-s-\frac13}\,_2F_1\left ( \frac23,\frac23;\frac43;x\right)\text{d}x.
$$
**Step 2**: Differentiating with respect to $s$, after some simplifications we arrive at
$$
\,_4F_3\left ( \frac13,\frac13,\frac23,\frac23;
1,\frac43,\frac43;1 \right ) 
=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac13 \right )^6 }{12\pi^2} +
\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}\,\Gamma\left ( \frac13 \right )^3} 
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x)}{x^{2/3}} 
\,_2F_1\left ( \frac23,\frac23;\frac43;1-x \right )\text{d}x}_{I}.
$$
Expanding the $\,_2F_1$, end up to evaluate
$$
I=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left ( \frac{2}{3}  \right )_n^2 }{
\left ( \frac43 \right )_n} \frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac13 \right )
\left ( \psi^{(0)}\left ( \frac13 \right ) -\psi^{(0)}
\left ( n+\frac43 \right )  \right )  }{\Gamma\left ( n+\frac43 \right ) }.
$$
**Step 3**: From [Entry 2, Entry 4](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/03/02/03/), we have
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left ( \frac23 \right )^2_n }{
\left ( \frac43 \right )_n(1)_n} \frac{\Gamma(n+a)}{\Gamma\left ( n+\frac{a+1}{2}+\frac13  \right ) } 
=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma\left ( \frac76 \right )\Gamma(a)\Gamma\left ( \frac{1-a}{2}+\frac13  \right )  }{
\Gamma\left ( \frac56 \right )^2 \Gamma\left ( \frac{1+a}{2}  \right ) \Gamma\left ( \frac{1-a}{2}+\frac23  \right )},
&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left ( \frac23 \right )^2_n }{
\left ( 1 \right )_n} \frac{\Gamma(n+a)}{\Gamma\left ( n+a+\frac13  \right )^2 } 
=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac{a}2+1 \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac{a}2-\frac13 \right )  }{
a\,\Gamma\left ( a-\frac13 \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac{a}2+\frac13 \right )^2  }.
\end{aligned}
Therefore
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left ( \frac23 \right )_n^2 }{
\left ( \frac43 \right )_n } \frac{\psi^{(0)}(n+1)-2\psi^{(0)}
\left ( n+\frac43 \right ) }{\Gamma\left ( n+\frac43 \right ) }
=\frac{\left ( 12\gamma-11\pi\sqrt{3}+27\ln(3)  \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac13 \right )^8 }{128\pi^4},\\
&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left ( \frac23 \right )_n^2 }{
\left ( \frac43 \right )_n } \frac{\psi^{(0)}(n+1)-\frac12\psi^{(0)}
\left ( n+\frac43 \right ) }{\Gamma\left ( n+\frac43 \right ) }
=\frac{\left ( \pi\sqrt{3}-3\gamma  \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac13 \right )^8 }{64\pi^4}.
\end{aligned}
We immediately solve
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left ( \frac23 \right )_n^2 }{
\left ( \frac43 \right )_n } \frac{\psi^{(0)}
\left ( n+\frac43 \right ) }{\Gamma\left ( n+\frac43 \right ) }
=\frac{\left ( -18\gamma+13\pi\sqrt{3}-27\ln(3)  \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac13 \right )^8 }{192\pi^4}.
$$
Eventually all these equations above allowed us to show
$$
I=-\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)^9}{4\sqrt{3}\pi^3}.\square
$$