# Proving $_4F_3\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},1;\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4}, \frac{3}{2};1\right)=\frac{\Gamma^8(1/4)}{768\pi^3}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, hypergeometric-function

I have been trying to Prove the following Sum.

$$\frac{\Gamma^2(5/4)}{\Gamma^2(3/4)}\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2r+1}\right)\frac{\Gamma^2(r+3/4)}{\Gamma^2(r+5/4)}=\frac{\Gamma^8(1/4)}{768\pi^3}$$

Or in terms of Pochhammer Symbol:

$$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2r+1}\right)\frac{(3/4)_r^2}{(5/4)_r^2}=\frac{\Gamma^8(1/4)}{768\pi^3}$$

One may convert it into a Hypergeometric Representation which gives:

$$_4F_3\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},1;\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},
\frac{3}{2};1\right)=\frac{1}{768\pi^3}\Gamma^8\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)$$

Also note that,
$$\sum_{i=1}^3b_i-\sum_{i=1}^{4}a_i=1$$

I just mentioned the above because I heard it's a kind of Property of such Functions.

I don't see how a $8$th Power Gamma Term appears.

The following [List](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric4F3/03/06/02/) at Functions.Wolfram doesn't have any similar ones nor am I able to use any formulas either.

One may use the following to Numerically Test it.

`N[HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2,3/4,3/4,1},{5/4,5/4,3/2},1],300]-Gamma[1/4]^8/Pi^3*1/768`

EDIT:

I was able to Convert it to an Integral:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(1+xy)-\ln(1-xy)}{\sqrt{xy(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}}dxdy=\frac{\Gamma^4(1/4)}{48}$$

Comment: What are $a_i,b_i$? [Similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3794044/prove-that-4f-3-left-frac13-frac13-frac23-frac231-frac43-frac431-right), maybe one of the methods used there will work here.

Comment: @user170231 It's the following $_4F_3(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4;b_1,b_2,b_3;x)$, I will also check upon that post once and try the same.

Comment: Using a formula from [Glasser](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.5968), the latter integral can be transformed into
\begin{equation}
 -2\int_0^1  \frac{\mathbf K(k) \ln k}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}dk
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf K(k)$ is the complete elliptic integral for the modulus $k$.

Comment: Any reason for this sum ? Is it related to physics or number theory ? How did you come up with it ?

Comment: @PaulEnta That is nice! Now that I see the result it seems that same can be derived from Moments of $K'(k)$.

Comment: @mick It was related to Evaluation of $$\int_0^1kK'K^2dk=\frac{1}{768\pi^2}\Gamma^8\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)$$ which was converted into the mentioned sum.

Comment: @MiracleInvoker Could you please show me the converting details between the sum and the integral?

Comment: @SetnessRamesory It is related to Fourier Legendre Expansions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have the following formula, which transforms a well-poised $_5F_4$ into two $1$-balanced $_4F_3$, here all $_pF_q$ are assume to be at $z=1$:
$$\begin{aligned}&{}_5 F_4\left(\begin{matrix}a,\quad b,\quad c,\quad d,\quad e\\1+a-b,\quad 1+a-c, \quad 1+a-d,\quad 1+a-e\end{matrix}\right) \\ &=  \frac{\Gamma (a-b+1) \Gamma (a-c+1) \Gamma (a-d+1) \Gamma (a-b-c-d+1)}{\Gamma (a+1) \Gamma (a-b-c+1) \Gamma (a-b-d+1) \Gamma (a-c-d+1)}  \times {}_4F_3\left(\begin{matrix}b, \quad c,\quad d,\quad \frac{a}{2}-e+1 \\ \frac{a}{2}+1, \quad d-a+b+c, \quad 1+a-e\end{matrix}\right)  \\ &\quad +\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{a}{2}+1\right) \Gamma (a-b+1) \Gamma (a-c+1) \Gamma (a-d+1) \Gamma (a-e+1) \Gamma (-a+b+c+d-1) \Gamma \left(\frac{3 a}{2}-b-c-d-e+2\right) }{\Gamma (a+1) \Gamma (b) \Gamma (c) \Gamma (d) \Gamma \left(\frac{a}{2}-e+1\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{3 a}{2}-b-c-d+2\right) \Gamma (2 a-b-c-d-e+2)} \\ &\quad \times {}_4F_3\left(\begin{matrix}a-b-c+1, \quad a-b-d+1,\quad a-c-d+1,\quad \frac{3 a}{2}-b-c-d-e+2 \\ a-b-c-d+2, \quad \frac{3 a}{2}-b-c-d+2, \quad 2 a-b-c-d-e+2\end{matrix}\right)  \end{aligned}$$
this is a special case of very-well-poised $_7F_6$ reduction formula, which can be found in Bailey's *Generalized hypergeometric series* p.29. Another proof using Barne's integral can be found in p.44 of same book.

Let $(a,b,c,d,e) = (1,1,1/2,3/4,3/4)$, LHS actually reduces to $_4F_3$, one term on RHS reduces to $_3F_2$ that can be summed using [Dixon's theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DixonsTheorem.html). The form will be

$$_4F_3\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},1 \\ \frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2}\end{matrix}\right)=\frac{\Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right) }{2 \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)} {}_4F_3\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},1 \\ \frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2}\end{matrix}\right)+\frac{\pi  \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^3}{2 \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^4}$$

Solving this gives $${}_4F_3\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},1 \\ \frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2}\end{matrix}\right) = \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^8}{768 \pi ^3}$$ as desired.

Comment: Amazing Answer! As a side note it seems that Functions.Wolfram doesn't mention all the Hypergeometric Identities?

Comment: @MiracleInvoker Of course no. Mankind still doesn't know what "all the hypergeometric identities" are.